# Typescript-React: array not visible as component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

todoApi.ts:

```
import axios, {AxiosResponse} from "axios";

const API_URL: string = "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/todo/";

export async function getTodos(filter: string): Promise<[]> {
    const response: AxiosResponse = await axios.get(API_URL, {
        headers: {
            filter: filter
        }
    });
    return await response.data;
}
```

Api response example:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Todo",
        "description": "Todo description",
        "done": false,
        "dateCreated": "2022-10-18",
        "deadline": "2022-10-19"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Todo1",
        "description": "Todo1 description",
        "done": false,
        "dateCreated": "2022-10-18",
        "deadline": "2022-10-20"
    }
]
```

App.tsx:  (excuse my bad naming conventions here)

```
import {getTodos} from "../api/todoApi";

let counter: number = 0;

export default function App(): JSX.Element {
    const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
 
    useEffect(() => {
        setInterval(() => {
            let _todos: ReactElement[] = [];

            getTodos(sessionStorage.getItem("search-key") as string).then((__todos) => {
                for (let i: number = 0; i < __todos.length; i++) {
                    const todo = __todos[i];
                    _todos.push(
                        <Todo key={counter} id={todo["id"]} name={todo["name"]}
                              description={todo["description"]}
                              dateCreated={todo["dateCreated"]} deadline={todo["deadline"]}
                              done={todo["done"] === "true"}/>
                    );
                    counter++;
                }
            });

            // @ts-ignore
            setTodos(_todos);
        }, 500);
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <div id={"todos"}>
                // some other components
                {todos}
                // some other components
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

- The array of to-dos doesn't render although when going to react elements or logging the 
      to-dos array I get the correct result.
- Todo component just returns a div with class todo and an h1 for every prop.

Comment: Storing components in the state is almost a bad idea. Do you get any errors?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski no i dont get any.about storing components in state, im new to react and i thought that was the only way for me to access todos from useEffect to update every 500ms, like i have it in the code sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

note: Storing your components in the state is a bad idea. Instead, store the data, and then map over the data to compose the components

---

Your issue is coming from the fact that you're loading the promise (`.then`) *after* you set your state (`setTodos(_todos);`) which means `_todos` is an empty array.

If you move the `setTodos(_todos);` below your `for(){}` loop, it will work. However, again, it is bad practice, and I urge you to continue research into better ways to do this :)

Comment: Thanks that fixed the issue.regarding my bad practice, im kinda new to react and didnt know.ill make sure to look into it.thanks for the help!

Comment: @GeorgeAthans of course, not a problem :) hope you get far!